# WordPress- have a specific type of "page/post" as "testimony". Possible? If so, how?

Tags: wordpress, customization

I'm implementing our school's website using WordPress as CMS. So far, it works well and I'm 80% done. Our website is basically 11 WordPress pages and a blog.

Now, there is one feature i'm not sure how to resolve. We want to have "testimonies" of past students to be displayed across WordPress pages, in a specific area of the page. They will either be videos or written text with an image.
They will be embedded on regular WordPress pages either a specific video for a specific page, or just random testimony video for a given page.

Is it possible to do that with WordPress? If so, how?

Thanks for any hints.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few Wordpress plugins which handle testimonials gracefully:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=testimony

Comment: ah. I didn't even think about plugins. I was more thinking about having a specific type of "posts" (like in a category "testimonials") which would only contain the link to the video/ or the body text. But then it means displaying a post inside a post so i figure that's not a workable option. I'm looking into your plugins suggestion now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with categories.  Create a testimony category and and then create a new template called 'testimony-page.php'.  In that template, put a separate [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) that pulls a random testimony from the database.  Voila, page in a page.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like building this yourself, it can be handled with custom post types. Here is a great guide that will give you a lot of useful information: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/

To manage my custom post types.

To query posts from a new post type, use something like:

```
query_posts({
   'post_type' => 'testimonials'
});
```

So, if you wanted to add testimonials to your site, you'd query them like above with whatever parameters you need, and do a simple loop to output the posts.